# can you append(add) space and/or hyphen characters to the end of match in regex?

Tags: java, string-formatting

exactly as the question sounds, I want to know if you can append or add a space character at the end of all matches or just certain matches

regex code I have

```
${Brand Name}${Colour}${Product Description}${ID}
```

what it spits out

```
Facille SnapBlackTablestop Snapkin Dispenser and Pack of Snapkins4696400

Brand Name:          Facille Snap
Colour:              Black
Product Description: Tablestop Snapkin Dispenser and Pack of Snapkins
ID:                  4696400
```

I want regex to return a usable line of text like this

```
Facille Snap - Black Tablestop Snapkin Dispenser and Pack of Snapkins - 4696400
```

Comment: `${Brand Name} ${Colour} ${Product Description} - ${ID}`?

Comment: What you have `${Brand Name}...` is not a regex.  It is a formatting pattern.  Please show the code you are using to execute this.

Comment: wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwww stupid me @Wug your right, I tried that earlier without escaping the characters...

Comment: @JimGarrison im running an app that you enter regex into to find matches, that is the code I entered. Each one of the things in the curly brackets is a property assigned to the html and the app will set up a new property by combining all of these

Comment: Well then, the app misuses the term "regex".

Comment: @JimGarrison well normally it uses regex and only regex, but right now it is searching through an Excel file that is hosted online. the most common code I use is <tag w/e id="yadda">(.*?)</tag> to capture text from a specific source, but apparently it runs different with an Excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those don't look like regexes to me.

As per the comments, you probably want to use this:

`${Brand Name} ${Colour} ${Product Description} - ${ID}`

Beyond that, you can split *CamelCase* text like this:

```
System.out.println(camelSplit("ThisIsAFunkyCamelString"));

/** Returns a copy of s with a space in front of each capital letter. */

public String camelSplit(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length < 2) {
        return s;
    }
    return s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(1).replaceAll("([A-Z])", " $1");
}
```

NOTE: The above method assumes that a space should be added in front of each capital letter.  You'll have to add more logic if you want it to deal with acronyms like `USA`.

Comment: thank you, I tried that simple solution right off the bat but didn't escape the hyphen which made it fail and not return anything. stupid error on my part

Comment: this app I'm using is accepts like a hybrid of text from html, java, and regex, its confusing at times when you don't know which rules it will take from what language

Answer (score 0):

Change your formatting pattern to:

```
${Brand Name} ${Colour} ${Product Description} - ${ID}
```